# How get laravel 8 notifications by notification type?

Tags: laravel

I have created two types of notification in laravel

1. Purchase and Sale
2. Product Order

How can I display two notifications type in laravel ?

```
{{Auth::user()->unreadNotifications}}
```

NOTIFICATIONS TABLE SCHEMA

```
public function up()     {   
Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {             

$table->uuid('id')->primary();   
$table->string('type');
$table->morphs('notifiable');             
$table->text('data'); 
$table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();             
$table->timestamps();         
});
```

it gives me all the notifications how can I seperate them or fetch only particular type of notifications from notification table...

Comment: please share your relationships as well as schema of unreadNotifications

Comment: `public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('type');
            $table->morphs('notifiable');
            $table->text('data');
            $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });` I haven't created relationships for it.

Comment: please add code in question not in comments